# How many Warships did General Kerensky take with him on the exodus?

Tags: battletech

I have just started to read the old Battletech books (I have come to Lethal Heritage) and the Clans are just introduced. Throughout the books I already read there is references to the great exodus but I haven't found any

I am wondering how many Warships (**Battleships and Dreadnaughts**) Kerensky took with him when he initiated the Exodus? (The total is 402 Warships and of those only 260 survived the civil war)